# How to remove a parent from a file or folder in google app script

Tags: google-apps-script

I have files with multiple parents. I want to extras and keep only ones I like. How to achieve this. Something similar to the statement illustrated in the code below

```
var parentCount=0;
var driveFile = DriveApp.getFileById(id); 
var parentFolder = driveFile.getParents();
while (parentFolder.hasNext()) {
 var folder = parentFolder.next();
 parentCount++;
 if(folder.getName()=="I don't want this")
   driveFile.removeParentLocation(folder) //Not a legal Method. needs workaround
}
```

Its easy to do from the web interface. see the x button next to locations.
[image]

Comment: How about changing "driveFile.removeParentLocation(folder)" to "folder.removeFile(driveFile)"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answered in comments above

```
var parentCount=0;
var driveFile = DriveApp.getFileById(id); 
var parentFolder = driveFile.getParents();
while (parentFolder.hasNext()) {
 var folder = parentFolder.next();
 parentCount++;
 if(folder.getName()=="I don't want this")
   driveFile.removeParentLocation(folder)
}
```

> Editor Comment: Note first comment above from @tanaike folder.removeFile(driveFile)